# ShopifyAPI InventoryLevel connect does not work

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-api

[I'm following the REST docs for InventoryLevel on Shopify.](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/inventorylevel#post-inventory-levels-connect)

I have instantiated a new session with:

```
    sesh = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain: current_shop.shopify_domain, token: current_shop.shopify_token, api_version: current_shop.api_version)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sesh)
```

And I cannot get it to work. By simply following the instructions as below:

```
inventory_level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.new
inventory_level.connect(body: {location_id: new_internal_variant.location.rest_id, inventory_item_id: new_internal_variant.inventory_item_id})
```

It returns

```
*** ArgumentError Exception: unknown keyword: :body
```

Then hacking around I try:

```
inventory_level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.new(params: {inventory_item_ids: new_internal_variant.inventory_item_id, location_ids: new_internal_variant.location.rest_id})
inventory_level.connect
```

I get the following error:

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `location_id' for #<ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel:0x000055bc2727aa68>
```

Which isn't even in the request.

Anyone ever get this to work?

EDIT:
I have an active session prior to the call. I create a session with:

```
sesh = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain: current_shop.shopify_domain, token: current_shop.shopify_token, api_version: current_shop.api_version)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sesh)
```

When I do this:

```
inventory_level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.new
```

I get this:

```
#<ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel:0x00005641959394a0 @attributes={}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false>
```

But then when following the directions with this:

```
inventory_level.connect( body: {inventory_item_id: 3968455XXXXX, location_id: 5212XXXX, relocate_if_necessary: true, disconnet_if_necessary: true})
```

I always get:

```
ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :body)
```

I've tried putting `body` into its own hash, I've tried `params` and nothing..

Comment: works for me, but in your case, you seem to have left out whether you're in a session or not. What do you get for your initial inventory_level object. Is it even valid. Start with that.

Comment: @DavidLazar yes this doesn't make any sense.. I can't seem to get it to work in product on a dev shop or anything.. I keep getting ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :body) I'll update the OP with more info